# how can i extract the text from XML?

Tags: python, xml

My goal is to extract each boxes, the shape, the text and the swimline that the box is in.

So far i've managed to extract every boxes and it's shape. For some reasons, the code recognise when there is text inside the box, but don't display it (instead it shows the emplacement of the hardware).

Any idea why?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Load the .VDX file
tree = ET.parse('Test VDX.vdx')
root = tree.getroot()

# Define the namespace used in the .VDX file
ns = {'visio': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/visio/2003/core'}

# Find all shape elements in the .VDX file
pages = root.findall('.//visio:Page', ns)
shapes = root.findall('.//visio:Shape', ns)

# Iterate over the shapes and extract information
for page in pages:
    page_id = page.get('ID')
    page_name = page.get('NameU')
    print(f"Page ID: {page_id}, Name: {page_name}")

for shape in shapes:
    shape_id = shape.get('ID')
    shape_name = shape.get('Name')
    shape_type = shape.get('Type')
    shape_text_element = shape.find('.//visio:Text', ns)
    if shape_text_element is not None:
        shape_text = shape_text_element.text
    else:
        shape_text = 'TExt'
    print(f"Shape ID: {shape_id}, Name: {shape_name}, Type: {shape_type}, Text: {shape_text}")
```

The file i'm working it's a xml file with .vdx from Microsoft Visio.

```
<Shape ID="21" Type="Shape" Name="Rectangle Fill:Marble.21">
      <XForm>
        <Angle>-0</Angle>
        <PinX>5.413385833333333</PinX>
        <PinY>6.181102430555556</PinY>
        <Width>1.377952777777778</Width>
        <Height>0.59055125</Height>
        <LocPinX>0.6889763888888889</LocPinX>
        <LocPinY>0.295275625</LocPinY>
      </XForm>
      <TextXForm>
        <TxtPinX F="Width*0.500000">1.322397232055664</TxtPinX>
        <TxtLocPinX F="Width*0.500000">1.322397232055664</TxtLocPinX>
        <TxtPinY F="Height*0.500000">0.4719645182291667</TxtPinY>
        <TxtLocPinY F="Height*0.500000">0.4719645182291667</TxtLocPinY>
        <TxtWidth F="Width*1">1.322397232055664</TxtWidth>
        <TxtHeight F="Height*1">0.4719645182291667</TxtHeight>
        <TxtAngle>-0</TxtAngle>
      </TextXForm>
      <Prop ID="0" NameU="Row_0">
        <Type>0</Type>
        <Value Unit="STR">Purchaser</Value>
        <Label/>
      </Prop>
      <Prop ID="1" NameU="Row_1">
        <Type>0</Type>
        <Value Unit="STR">0</Value>
        <Label>Cost</Label>
      </Prop>
      <Prop ID="2" NameU="Row_2">
        <Type>0</Type>
        <Value Unit="STR">0</Value>
        <Label>Duration</Label>
      </Prop>
      <Prop ID="3" NameU="Row_3">
        <Type>0</Type>
        <Value Unit="STR">0</Value>
        <Label>Resources</Label>
      </Prop>
      <Misc>
        <ObjType>1</ObjType>
      </Misc>
      <Line>
        <LinePattern>1</LinePattern>
        <LineWeight>0.00333333</LineWeight>
        <LineColor>0</LineColor>
        <LineColorTrans>0</LineColorTrans>
        <Rounding>0</Rounding>
        <LineCap>0</LineCap>
      </Line>
      <Fill>
        <FillPattern>1</FillPattern>
        <FillForegnd>#e8eef7</FillForegnd>
        <FillForegndTrans>0</FillForegndTrans>
        <ShdwPattern>0</ShdwPattern>
        <ShdwForegnd>#ffffff</ShdwForegnd>
        <ShdwForegndTrans>0</ShdwForegndTrans>
        <ShapeShdwType>1</ShapeShdwType>
        <ShapeShdwOffsetX>0.11811</ShapeShdwOffsetX>
        <ShapeShdwOffsetY>-0.11811</ShapeShdwOffsetY>
      </Fill>
      <Geom IX="0">
        <NoFill>0</NoFill>
        <NoLine>0</NoLine>
        <MoveTo IX="1">
          <X F="Width*0.000000">0</X>
          <Y F="Height*1.000000">0.5905512499999995</Y>
        </MoveTo>
        <LineTo IX="2">
          <X F="Width*1.000000">1.377952777777777</X>
          <Y F="Height*1.000000">0.5905512499999995</Y>
        </LineTo>
        <LineTo IX="3">
          <X F="Width*1.000000">1.377952777777777</X>
          <Y F="Height*0.000000">0</Y>
        </LineTo>
        <LineTo IX="4">
          <X F="Width*0.000000">0</X>
          <Y F="Height*0.000000">0</Y>
        </LineTo>
        <LineTo IX="5">
          <X F="Width*0.000000">0</X>
          <Y F="Height*1.000000">0.5905512499999995</Y>
        </LineTo>
      </Geom>
      <LayerMem>
        <LayerMember>0</LayerMember>
      </LayerMem>
      <Connection ID="0">
        <X F="Width*0.000000">0</X>
        <Y F="Width*0.214286">0.2952755555555563</Y>
        <Type>0</Type>
      </Connection>
      <Connection ID="1">
        <X F="Width*1.000000">1.377952777777777</X>
        <Y F="Width*0.214286">0.2952755555555563</Y>
        <Type>0</Type>
      </Connection>
      <Connection ID="2">
        <X F="Width*0.500000">0.6889763888888886</X>
        <Y F="Width*0.000000">0</Y>
        <Type>0</Type>
      </Connection>
      <Connection ID="3">
        <X F="Width*0.500000">0.6889763888888886</X>
        <Y F="Width*0.428571">0.5905512499999995</Y>
        <Type>0</Type>
      </Connection>
      <TextBlock>
        <LeftMargin>0.0277778</LeftMargin>
        <RightMargin>0.0277778</RightMargin>
        <TopMargin>0.0277778</TopMargin>
        <BottomMargin>0.0277778</BottomMargin>
        <VerticalAlign>1</VerticalAlign>
        <DefaultTabStop>0</DefaultTabStop>
      </TextBlock>
      <Char IX="0">
        <Font>0</Font>
        <Color>0</Color>
        <Style>0</Style>
        <Size>0.138889</Size>
        <ColorTrans>0</ColorTrans>
      </Char>
      <Para IX="0">
        <IndFirst>0</IndFirst>
        <IndLeft>0</IndLeft>
        <IndRight>0</IndRight>
        <SpLine>-1.2</SpLine>
        <SpBefore>0</SpBefore>
        <HorzAlign>1</HorzAlign>
      </Para>
      <Text><cp IX="0"/><pp IX="0"/>Attach Pos to invoice and complete coding form</Text>
    </Shape>
```

i've tried to convert .text or to convert it in string but nothing works.

Comment: Please add actual and expected output. Also, please add root element with namespaces so question complies with a [mcve]

Comment: `visio:Text` text content is at `shape_text = shape_text_element.tail` in this case since there's another element before the actual text content. See [tail attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail)

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the text attribute of the `<Text>`-tag and the tail attribute(s) of all children. Taking into account that either can be None, code should look something like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = ET.fromstring('''<Text><cp IX="0"/><pp IX="0"/>Attach Pos to invoice and complete coding form</Text>''')
textelem = xml
text = "" if textelem.text is None else textelement.text
for child in textelem:
    text += "" if child.tail is None else child.tail
print(text)
```